# How to rotate the arrow image along with MKMapview rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, annotations, mkmapview, cllocationmanager

My view controller has two custom annotation view as source & destination. I successfully made a overlay path between them and set the destination arrow icon's direction in the same line of overlay path. Now when i rotate the map on simulator by pressing 'Alt' key in keyboard, the arrow icon does not rotate with the overlay path direction. To rotate the arrow icon, i took the map view camera angle and tried to update the arrow icon direction by that camera angle but does not seems to work properly. Below is the code snippet. How can i do this ? Is there any better solution ? Any kind of help will be much appreciable. Thanks.

In My ViewController.m file -

```
#import "MoreController.h"
#import "Annotation.h"

@interface MoreController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) Annotation *destination;
@end

@implementation MoreController

- (void) makeOverlayPathBetweenConsecutiveLocation:(Annotation *)source toDest:(Annotation *)destination {
    MKMapPoint startPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(source.coordinate);
    MKMapPoint endPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(destination.coordinate);

    MKMapPoint *pointArray = malloc(sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D) * 2);
    pointArray[0] = startPoint;
    pointArray[1] = endPoint;
    MKPolyline *routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithPoints:pointArray count:2];
    [self.mapView addOverlay:routeLine];
}

- (CLLocationDirection) getDirection:(Annotation *)source toDest:(Annotation *)destination {
    CLLocation *startLocation = [source getLocation];
    CLLocation *endLocation = [destination getLocation];

    //Determine the direction
    double lat1 = startLocation.coordinate.latitude * M_PI / 180.0;
    double lon1 = startLocation.coordinate.longitude * M_PI / 180.0;
    double lat2 = endLocation.coordinate.latitude * M_PI / 180.0;
    double lon2 = endLocation.coordinate.longitude * M_PI / 180.0;

    double dLon = lon2 - lon1;
    double y = sin(dLon) * cos(lat2);
    double x = cos(lat1) * sin(lat2) - sin(lat1) * cos(lat2) * cos(dLon);
    double radiansBearing = atan2(y, x);

    CLLocationDirection directionBetweenPoints = radiansBearing * 180.0 / M_PI;

    return directionBetweenPoints;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    CLLocationCoordinate2D sourceCoordinate = {
        51.0455555556,
        1.94722222222
    };

    CLLocationCoordinate2D destCoordinate = {
        51.0491666667,
        1.80805555556
    };

    Annotation *sourceAnnotation = [[Annotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:sourceCoordinate forTitle:@"Source" forSubTitle:@"From"];
    [sourceAnnotation setTypeOfAnnotation:PIN_ANNOTATION];

    Annotation *destAnnotation = [[Annotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:destCoordinate forTitle:@"Destination" forSubTitle:@"To"];
    [destAnnotation setTypeOfAnnotation:ARROW_ANNOTATION];

    [destAnnotation setDirection:[self getDirection:sourceAnnotation toDest:destAnnotation]];
    [self makeOverlayPathBetweenConsecutiveLocation:sourceAnnotation toDest:destAnnotation];

    [self.mapView addAnnotation:sourceAnnotation];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:destAnnotation];
    [self.mapView setRegion:MKCoordinateRegionMake(destCoordinate, MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.3, 0.3))
                   animated:YES];

    self.destination = destAnnotation;
}

- (MKOverlayRenderer *) mapView:(MKMapView *) mapView viewForOverlay:(id) overlay {
    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolyline class]]) {
        MKPolyline *route = overlay;
        MKPolylineRenderer *routeRenderer = [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc] initWithPolyline:route];
        routeRenderer.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        routeRenderer.lineWidth = 2.0;
        return routeRenderer;
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}

//Determine the direction of arrow icon
- (UIImage*)rotatedImage:(UIImage*)sourceImage byDegreesFromNorth:(double)degrees {
    CGSize rotateSize =  sourceImage.size;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rotateSize);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, rotateSize.width/2, rotateSize.height/2);
    CGContextRotateCTM(context, ( degrees * M_PI/180.0 ) );
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),
                       CGRectMake(-rotateSize.width/2,-rotateSize.height/2,rotateSize.width, rotateSize.height),
                       sourceImage.CGImage);
    UIImage *rotatedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return rotatedImage;
}

//Make custom annotaion pin if the annotation is of ship's current position
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *) mapView viewForAnnotation: (id) annotation {
    MKAnnotationView *customAnnotationView;
    NSString *reuseId = @"custom";

    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[Annotation class]]){
        Annotation *_annotation = (Annotation*)annotation;
        if ([[_annotation typeOfAnnotation] isEqualToString:PIN_ANNOTATION]) {
            customAnnotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseId];
            [customAnnotationView setCanShowCallout:YES];
        } else {
            customAnnotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseId];

            //Determine the direction
            UIImage *arrowImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow"];
            double direction = [_annotation direction];
            [customAnnotationView setImage:[self rotatedImage:arrowImage byDegreesFromNorth:direction]];
            [customAnnotationView setCanShowCallout:YES];
        }
    } else {
        return nil;
    }

    return customAnnotationView;
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
    MKMapCamera *camera = self.mapView.camera;
    CLLocationDirection mapAngle = camera.heading;
    NSLog(@"map angle :  %f", mapAngle);

    if (mapAngle && (self.destination != nil)) {
        //Determine the arrow icon direction
        [self.mapView removeAnnotation:self.destination];
        [self.destination setDirection:mapAngle];
        [self.mapView addAnnotation:self.destination];
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

and My custom annotation file -

```
#import "Annotation.h"

@implementation Annotation

@synthesize coordinate=_coordinate;

- (id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate forTitle:(NSString *)title forSubTitle:(NSString *)territory {
    self = [super init];

    if (self != nil) {
        _coordinate = coordinate;
        _name = title;
        _territory = territory;
    }

    return self;
}

-(CLLocation *) getLocation {
    return [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude: _coordinate.latitude longitude: _coordinate.longitude];
}


//Add a Callout
- (NSString*) title {
    return self.name;
}

//Add a Callout
- (NSString*) subtitle {
    return self.territory;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

In which way it works unproperly?

There is at least one obvious error in your code. According to the CoreLocation documentation, CLLocationDirection must be positive, a negative value indicates an invalid direction. To force this replace in your getDirection method the string:

```
CLLocationDirection directionBetweenPoints = radiansBearing * 180.0 / M_PI;
```

with two as follows:

```
double angle = radiansBearing * 180.0 / M_PI;
CLLocationDirection directionBetweenPoints = (angle>=0)? angle : 360+angle;
```

Hope this will help.